# Is it possible to display AdSense ads in a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, adsense

Is displaying google adsense ads on android / ios app against the google adsense terms and conditions?

I have a site with 60% traffic from mobile  and my site is already responsive .

I'm thinking of making an App for my website !

Will my adsense revenue decrease if i make an app for the site !

What is the difference between adsense and admob !

As far as i know , Adsense is for webmaster / website whereas admob is for app developers! Can some one explain the same in layman term.

Comment: refer https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68724?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

**No You Can't**
The use of AdSense for mobile in a mobile application is a violation of AdSense policies. A mobile application constitutes any downloadable application, even if a WebView is used to display the ad. Any AdSense for mobile ad units found in mobile applications will be disabled. If you’re looking for an advertising solution for your mobile application, please sign up for AdMob, Google’s leading mobile advertising display product.

[see here official documents](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68724?hl=en)

Comment: I'm not seeing anything forbidding the use of AdSense in a mobile app in your link, its content may have changed. In the AdSense ToS https://www.google.com/adsense/new/localized-terms?hl=en_US , AdMob is referred to here: "Other than distributing content via the AdMob SDK, you may not copy, modify, distribute, sell, or lease any part of our Services ... ". So again, it's not explicitly forbidding not using AdMob. Maybe their ToS changed? Or do you have an updated link?

Answer (score 0):

As you know that adsense is  to show ad in web and admob is to show ad in mobile. of course if you want to load adsense in you mobile app. You can use webview component. I am not sure about that will it load or not. But I will suggest you to go with admob because admob show the ad which are relevant to mobile user. which can increse your revenue.

While showing adsense ad which is relevant to web user. you mobile user might not click on that ad. which falls down your revenue. There are also many other option in your admob. like showing video ad, full screen ad etc. And many other provider available in the market to show ad in mobile.